# How to get values of EditText from another model / Make an o

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to make an on-click method for recycle List items.
I have found that you can make it inside the Adapter you have made for the list inside the OnBindViewHolder, and it works, however, I do not have access to the EditTexts that are in the Activity where the Adapter is used , I was wondering if there is a way to import them to be used in the Adapter ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you mean you don't have access? Please post relevant code, so we have a starting place to work from.

Comment: In general, a good approach is to do none of that sort of thing in your view layer. A ViewModel could have access to that information, so you should just have your `onClick` methods call the ViewModel and let it deal with things like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it, You have to use **Interface** for this purpose.

Interface will pass your data from Adapter to your Activity having that EditText.
Then you update your EditText accordingly.

Create an Interface

```
   public interface DataTransferInterface {
     public void onItemClicked(String data);
   }
```

Create Object of Interface in Adapter

```
DataTransferInterface dtInterface;
```

Initialize it in Constructor of your adapter

```
public MyAdapter(DataTransferInterface dtInterface) {   
   this.dtInterface = dtInterface;
}
```

When Any item is Clicked in Adapter pass data to Activity

```
    item.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            dtInterface.onItemClicked("Data to be passed here");
        }
    });
```

Now in your Activity

implement that interface like:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements DataTransferInterface {
```

When you implement Interface in Activity, It will show error to implement its required methods. SO,

```
@Override
 public void onItemClicked(String Data) {
 // TODO Update your EditText Here
 
 }
```

Initialize your adapter like

```
myAdapter = new MyAdapter(this);
```

If you find any difficulties, You can read more [here](https://abhinayme.medium.com/android-passing-data-from-adapter-to-activity-using-interface-8a6e9a13f6e0)